# Android webview tab support

Tags: android, webview

I've been searching around quite a bit but haven't been able to find what I've been looking for maybe I'm using the wrong keywords or something. Anyway I'm building a custom android browser app and I'd like to support multiple tabs. Does a webview support multiple tabs or am I just supposed to save the state of the webview some how in like a database or something and then when they press the tab just restore that state?

What I'm basically asking is, is there a way to support multiple windows already in place or is this something we have to just handle on our own?

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: Do you want multiple webviews in different  activities or multiple webviews in Tabs? Now when I say tabs, I mean the `TabWidget`. The number of tabs would be fixed here, which I think is not the thing you are looking for. Are you looking for some browser like experience ?

Comment: I'm looking for like a browser experience something like this http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQctnI-GwOFB-AY8V3ugghvG5p2yG9IzPUEF3b8TvtyJ9yzKSgw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never really got what I was looking for, so what I ended up doing was saving the state of the webviews in a database so i could restore it when the app was reopened. I then knew how many rows were in my database was equal to the number of webviews i would need to add and restore the state for programmatically. Reason for this was that i was unable to restore the webviews state outside of the oncreate or even just a second time for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for `TabWidget`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html

Comment: not so much I have it already set up like this http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQctnI-GwOFB-AY8V3ugghvG5p2yG9IzPUEF3b8TvtyJ9yzKSgw using a listview with swipe to dismiss rows but when i press the row i'm wondering how to restore the state i guess is a better way of putting it basically there's only one webview so it works more like the chrome app or androids stock browser app